# How to loop over a string and create a dictionary that counts the number of Characters are in that string

Tags: swift, xcode

```
let input = "aa bb c"
let expected: [Character: Int] = [
            "a": 2,
            "b": 2,
            "c": 1,
        ]
```

Heres my code. Any idea what I may be doing wrong?

```
func createCounter(string: String) {
    var charArr: [Character] = []
    let mappedChar = charArr.map { ($0, 1)}
    let counts = Dictionary(mappedChar, uniquingKeysWith: +)
    
    for char in string {
        if (char != " ") {
            charArr.append(char)
        }
    }
    
    print(counts)
    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out all I need to do was create a new string without the empty spaces, create and empty dictionary and loop over the new string. Heres my new code.

```
    var newString: String = ""
    var countDict: [Character: Int] = [:]
    
    for char in string {
        if (char != " ") {
            newString.append(char)
        }
    }
    
    for char in newString {
        if (countDict[char] != nil) {
            countDict[char]! += 1
        } else {
            countDict[char] = 1
        }
    }
    
    print(countDict)
    
}
```

Comment: There is no need for `newString`, you're just adding an unnecessary step.